# Left shift unsigned byte, a better way?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have an array of bytes (because unsigned byte isn't an option) and need to take 4 of them into a 32 bit int. I'm using this:

```
byte rdbuf[] = new byte[fileLen+1];
int i = (rdbuf[i++]) | ((rdbuf[i++]<<8)&0xff00) | ((rdbuf[i++]<<16)&0xff0000) | ((rdbuf[i++]<<24)&0xff000000);
```

If i don't do all the logical ands, it sign extends the bytes which is clearly not what I want.

In c this would be a no brainer. Is there a better way in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not have to do this, you can use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
int i = ByteBuffer.wrap(rdbuf).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

If you have many ints to read, the code becomes:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(rdbuf).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

while (buf.remaining() >= 4) // at least four bytes
    i = bb.getInt();
```

Javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). Recommended for use in any situation where binary data has to be dealt with (whether you read or write such data). Can do little endian, big endian and even native ordering. (NOTE: big endian by default).

(edit: @PeterLawrey rightly mentions that this looks like little endian data, fixed code extract -- also, see his answer for how to wrap the contents of a file directly into a `ByteBuffer`)

NOTES:

- `ByteOrder` has a static method called `.nativeOrder()`, which returns the byte order used by the underlying architecture;
- a `ByteBuffer` has a builtin offset; the current offset can be queried using `.position()`, and modified using `.position(int)`; `.remaining()` will return the number of bytes left to read from the current offset until the end;
- there are relative methods which will read from/write at the buffer's current offset, and absolute methods, which will read from/write at an offset you specify.

Comment: It's in `java.nio` @steveh

Comment: +1 The bitness appears to be little endian so you might need `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm too used to network order :( Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Comment: When I see a comparison with C I assume the bitness is just whatever the machine uses and most people use little endian machines. :|

Comment: that's great except the ints i want are all over the array, i have an index into the array 'i' (i just notice i used 'i' twice in my original question, my bad), anyhow, what is the java equivalent of this: int j = ByteBuffer.wrap(&rdbuf[i]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

Comment: this works byte[] tmpBuf = { rdbuf[i++], rdbuf[i++], rdbuf[i++], rdbuf[i++] }; int eventType = ByteBuffer.wrap(tmpBuf).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt(); but it terms of efficiency, i doubt its much better than my original code, thanks anyhow

Comment: @fge sorry, i don't understand your last comment at all, can you elaborate? thanks

Comment: @steveh just initialize your ByteBuffer: `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(rdbuf).byteOrder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`; and then call `.getInt()` repeatedly on `bb` (of course, check that there are remaining bytes before you do so)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading into a byte[] which you have to wrap with a ByteBuffer which does the shift/mask for you, you can use a direct ByteBuffer which avoid all this overhead.

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(filename).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(fc.size()).order(ByteBuffer.nativeOrder());
fc.read(bb);
bb.flip();
while(bb.remaining() > 0) {
    int n = bb.getInt(); // grab 32-bit from direct memory without shift/mask etc.
    short s = bb.getShort(); // grab 16-bit from direct memory without shift/mask etc.

    // get a String with an unsigned 16 bit length followed by ISO-8859-1 encoding.
    int len = bb.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) sb.append((char) (bb.get() & 0xFF));
    String text = sb.toString(); 
}
fc.close();
```

Comment: that looks helpful but my data read from file is a mix of ints, shorts and strings so i have to handle every bit of data on a case by case basis

Comment: oh, i see, you can use it to get any size object, cool, this may be a better way to do it, thanks

Comment: @steveh I have added examples for reading a short and a String, you can also read float, double etc.